# Flutter: Help evaluating function and displaying output with button press in flutter

Tags: function, flutter, dart, widget, output

I want to make an app clone of https://sleepyti.me/ Here is my current layout: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDZIT.jpg

I don't have all the functions made yet but am struggling with displaying results on button press. My function is:

```
void CalcBedTime(){
  var bedArr = [];
  DateTime nowDate = DateTime.now();
  for(var i = 0; i >= 7; i++){
    var nowHour = nowDate.hour;
    var newHour1 = nowDate.add(Duration(minutes: 90));
    String formatDate1 = DateFormat.jm().format(newHour1);
    bedArr.add(formatDate1);
  }
  print(bedArr);
}
```

Since this current function has no time input im currently just working on the function that takes time to wake up if you fall asleep at the current time. I'm also not sure if I should keep the function void and just have it print the return array or have it return the array value. My button is:

```
FlatButton(
                color: Colors.blue,
                textColor: Colors.white,
                disabledColor: Colors.grey,
                disabledTextColor: Colors.black,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                splashColor: Colors.blueAccent,
                onPressed:  ()   {  
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SleepNowPage(title: 'Sleep Now Page',)),
                  );

                  /*...*/
                },
                child: Text(
                  "I'm going to sleep now" ,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                ),
              )
```

Im not quite sure how or where to evaluate the function and then how to give the return array to be printed out. My SleepNowPage has:

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
   
    title: Text(widget.title),
  ),
  body: Center(
    
    child: Column(
      
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(
            'If you sleep now you should wake up at: \n '
        ),

      ],
    ),
  ),
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: _incrementCounter,
    tooltip: 'Increment',
    child: Icon(Icons.add),
  ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
);
```

Sorry if this isn't easy to understand I'm new to flutter and would like any help I could get.

Answer (score 0):

try this function :

```
  List<String> calcBedTime({
int hour,
int minute,
int second,
}) {
int sleepCycle = 90;
bool useCurrentTime;
if (hour != null && minute != null && second != null) {
  useCurrentTime = false;
} else {
  useCurrentTime = true;
}
DateTime nowDate = useCurrentTime
    ? DateTime.now()
    : DateTime.parse('2020-02-27 $hour:$minute:$second');

List<DateTime> bedArr = [
  nowDate.add(Duration(minutes: sleepCycle * 1)),
  nowDate.add(Duration(minutes: sleepCycle * 2)),
  nowDate.add(Duration(minutes: sleepCycle * 3)),
];
List<String> bedArrInHours =
    bedArr.map((item) => '${item.hour}:${item.minute}').toList();
print(bedArrInHours);
return bedArrInHours;
}
```

if you want the times if you fall asleep right now just use :

```
calcBedTime();
```

the result will be :

```
[19:54, 21:24, 22:54]
```

if you want waking up times if you sleep at a specific time just pass the optional parameters(just make sure the provided values are two characters long) :

```
calcBedTime(hour: 12 , minute: 30 , second: 10);
```

Note: this function only returns 3 sleep times, you can add more by hardcoding it just like I did or better yet do it using a for loop which is pretty simple.
Note2: the date of 2020:02:27 does not really matter just to use a format that is accepted by DateTime.parse().

Comment: Thank you I really appreciate the updated method. My next question is how would I go about evaluating that function on a button press and displaying it on my page? I'f I evaluate the function on the button press how do I get the return message to display the times? Thank you for your help :)

Comment: you can accept the return value from the function and store it in a variable of type List, then make another variable in your page state then use setState and now you have your data available to you, you can use anywhere anyhow you like.